# Deleting off-topic answers.

Tags: discussion, moderation, deleted-answers

I just ran across [this](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5516/cleaning-up-throw-up/7860#7860) deleted answer, which missed the fact that the question was specifically about halachah on Shabbat.

I don't feel that the appropriate response was to delete this answer, just for missing the halachic question involved. The answer had at least some shaychus to the question, so the appropriate thing to do here is let the readers vote it down.

I can't even vote to undelete this answer since it was deleted by the moderators. Could you moderators be careful to apply your moderation superpowers sparingly?

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up. I'll not undelete it, as, after all, it _is_ irrelevant (and it was deleted long ago), but I'll try and be careful about future such deletions so long as I'm a mod.

Comment: @msh210: Thanks

Comment: The answer in question was not only off-topic but also obnoxious and therefore corrosive to the community. If it had any content of value, I'd have edited out the obnoxious part and/or commented to the author.